# Probability Die Problem

Tags: probability

A die is thrown again and again until three sixes are obtained. Find the probability of obtaining the third six in the sixth throw of the die.

Answer (score 1):

Here $n=5$

$p = p(\text{six}) = 1/6  $

$∴q = 1-1/6 = 5/6$

$∴  p (\text{Obtaining third six in the sixth throw})$

$=p(\text{obtaining two sixes in first five throws and a six in the sixth throw})$

$=  p(\text{obtaining two sixes in first five throws}).\frac{1}{6}$
$= {5\choose2}×(\frac{5}{6})^{5-2}(\frac{1}{6})^{2}\frac{1}{6}$

$= \dfrac{5.4}{2.1}(\frac{5}{6})^{3}(\frac{1}{6})^{3}$
$= \dfrac{10×125}{6^6} = \frac{625}{23328}$

Hence the probability of obtaining the third six in the sixth throw of the die is $\frac{625}{23328}$
Here is the reference for this: [maths important questions](https://www.4ono.com/cbse-12th-maths-most-important-questions-chapter-wise-pdf-download/)

Answer (score 0):

Rolling 1 dice, the probability of having a "6" is $1/6$.
If you roll a dice $n$ times, the number of "6" follows a Binomial distribution.

To have the third "6" on the 6th roll, it means that you'll have two "6" in the first five rolls and that the 6th roll gave "6".

Can you compute the rest?